# How do i resolve a KeyError in python? check the code below

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def myFUNC (e):
  return e["Points"]

team_stats = [
            {"76ers" : {"Wins" : 22,
                       "Losses" : 12,
                       "Points" : 647},
            "Nets" :  {"Wins" : 22,
                       "Losses" : 13,
                       "Points" : 629},
            "Bucks" :  {"Wins" : 21,
                       "Losses" : 13,
                       "Points" : 618}}
              ]
print(team_stats.sort(key=myFUNC))
```

```
KeyError: 'Points'
```

Comment: What is the list for?

Comment: Your `team_stats` is a `list` of `dict` of `dicts`. Close the dictionaries a bit earlier (add a `}` after `"Points": 647}},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get `KeyError` is because you trying to access the key `"Points"` from the outer level of the dictionary, where it does not belong, and even if it did, with the current structure, you will see no difference in the result.

You have a single `dict` inside a `list`, there is nothing to `sort`. If you want to sort the `dict`, that is only possible if you are using `3.7+`, because from `3.7` onwards, [`dict`s in Python are guaranteed to maintain order](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html). If you do meet the version requirement, then use:

```
def myFUNC (e):
  return e[1]["Points"]

team_stats = [
            {"76ers" : {"Wins" : 22,
                       "Losses" : 12,
                       "Points" : 647},
            "Nets" :  {"Wins" : 22,
                       "Losses" : 13,
                       "Points" : 629},
            "Bucks" :  {"Wins" : 21,
                       "Losses" : 13,
                       "Points" : 618}}
              ]
result = [dict(sorted(team_stats[0].items(), key=myFUNC))]
print(result)
```

Which gives

```
[{'Bucks': {'Wins': 21, 'Losses': 13, 'Points': 618},
  'Nets': {'Wins': 22, 'Losses': 13, 'Points': 629},
  '76ers': {'Wins': 22, 'Losses': 12, 'Points': 647}}]
```

If you do not meet the version requirement, you need to use an [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
# replace the `result` line with this:
result = [OrderedDict(sorted(team_stats[0].items(), key=myFUNC))]
```

Which gives:

```
[OrderedDict([('Bucks', {'Wins': 21, 'Losses': 13, 'Points': 618}),
              ('Nets', {'Wins': 22, 'Losses': 13, 'Points': 629}),
              ('76ers', {'Wins': 22, 'Losses': 12, 'Points': 647})])]
```

But I don't see why you need the list here.

Also, `list().sort()` modifies the `list` in-place, which not only is useless here, printing this will return `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you meant is this maybe?

```
def myFUNC (i):
  return i[1]["Points"]

team_stats =  {"76ers" : {"Wins" : 22,
                       "Losses" : 12,
                       "Points" : 647},
            "Nets" :  {"Wins" : 22,
                       "Losses" : 13,
                       "Points" : 629},
            "Bucks" :  {"Wins" : 21,
                       "Losses" : 13,
                       "Points" : 618}}

print(sorted(team_stats.items(), key=myFUNC))
```

You sort each name by the points.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a dictionary inside of list, so when you try to sort the list, it is looking at the outer dictionary, and not the inner ones.

A solution is to use just the dictionary items as follows:

```
team_stats =     {"76ers" : {"Wins" : 22,
                       "Losses" : 12,
                       "Points" : 647},
            "Nets" :  {"Wins" : 22,
                       "Losses" : 13,
                       "Points" : 629},
            "Bucks" :  {"Wins" : 21,
                       "Losses" : 13,
                       "Points" : 618}}
sorted_teams = list(team_stats.items())  
sorted_teams.sort(key = lambda team : team[1]["Points"])   
# [('Bucks', {'Wins': 21, 'Losses': 13, 'Points': 618}), ('Nets', {'Wins': 22, 'Losses': 13, 'Points': 629}), ('76ers', {'Wins': 22, 'Losses': 12, 'Points': 647})]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store your `dict` outside of a list, you can sort it quite simply.

You can also keep your output as a `dict` by enclosing the `sorted()` method in `dict()`

```
team_stats =  {"76ers" : {"Wins" : 22,
                   "Losses" : 12,
                   "Points" : 647},
        "Nets" :  {"Wins" : 22,
                   "Losses" : 13,
                   "Points" : 629},
        "Bucks" :  {"Wins" : 21,
                   "Losses" : 13,
                   "Points" : 618}}

dict(sorted(team_stats.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['Points']))

#{'Bucks': {'Wins': 21, 'Losses': 13, 'Points': 618}, 'Nets': {'Wins': 22, 'Losses': 13, 'Points': 629}, '76ers': {'Wins': 22, 'Losses': 12, 'Points': 647}}

# in reverse
dict(sorted(team_stats.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['Points'], reverse=True))
#{'76ers': {'Wins': 22, 'Losses': 12, 'Points': 647}, 'Nets': {'Wins': 22, 'Losses': 13, 'Points': 629}, 'Bucks': {'Wins': 21, 'Losses': 13, 'Points': 618}}
```